# How do I use bootstrapping to compare more than two means?

Tags: nonparametric

I'm trying to use non-parametric bootstrapping to compare mean values in a 2 (between) by 4 (within) experimental design. I cannot use mixed ANOVA because the sample values are not normally distributed. I basically need to get a probability value of obtaining the measured means under the null hypothesis to test for two main effects -- first of the between factor, than the within factor -- as well as their interaction. I'm familiar with using bootstrapping to compare two means (shuffle the group labels, or take the difference and shuffle the sign of difference), but can I extend this to compare 4 within factor levels, and then to the interaction effect? If so, what is the best way to do these comparisons?

Comment: You need to use a cluster bootstrap where you resample *participants* (not observations) and compute your quantities of interest within each bootstrap replication. You can compute as many quantities as you want within each replication (e.g., all 4 means, contrasts between them, and contrasts between those contrasts).